# How to calculate performance metrics when my model returns an interval?

Tags: regression, time-series, model-evaluation, prediction-interval, prophet

I'm doing time series forecasting using Prophet. My forecasting model returns not only a prediction `y_hat`, but also an [uncertainty interval](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/uncertainty_intervals.html) `y_hat_lower` and `y_hat_upper`.

I wanted to calculate some metrics, like RMSE, MAE, etc. to evaluate the model's performance but don't know how to incorporate the interval in the calculation.

Should I be trying to do that? Normally, how do people evaluate these kinds of predictions?

Comment: Hi @CarlosGDCJ, welcome to CV. What is `y_hat_lower/upper`? Is it a 95% confidence interval? Prediction interval? Mean +/- one standard error?

Comment: @AlexJ I edited the question adding more context.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure. I am not familiar with an "uncertainty interval" - it appears to be something Bayesian but I don't know Prophet so can't say for sure. Usually, to calculate RMSE/MAE, you would calculate it with the [usual formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation), which should be available if you have the raw data and the prediction `y_hat` from the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If these are prediction intervals (and thus *not* confidence intervals, [there is a difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info)!) for a prespecified coverage probability, then one can use [interval scores](https://forecasting-encyclopedia.com/theory.html#point_forecast_accuracy_measures). These can be scaled to be comparable between different time series (if this is what you are working with).

If these are confidence intervals, then you are probably out of luck, because CIs by definition pertain to unobservable parameters.

Comment: My background in statistics is too weak for me to say I understood every word in your answer, but it was helpful nonetheless. I'm doing time series forecasting using Prophet, and my "interval" is Prophet's uncertainty interval. I initially thought it was a confidence interval, but after reading some of your references I'm leaning towards a prediction interval. If it isn't too much trouble, can you help me find out? [This is a short explanation about Prophet's interval](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/uncertainty_intervals.html#uncertainty-in-the-trend)

Comment: That is a wonderful question, which I don't know the answer to (although it does sound a little more like it's PIs), so I posted it as such: [Are Prophet's "uncertainty intervals" confidence intervals or prediction intervals?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/619860/1352)

Comment: Thank you! It seems I'm dealing with prediction intervals. I'll look into interval scores then.