# Are Prophet's "uncertainty intervals" confidence intervals or prediction intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, prediction-interval, prophet

> By default Prophet will return uncertainty intervals for the forecast `yhat`.

Unfortunately, [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/uncertainty_intervals.html) about those "uncertainty intervals" is extremely vague, and it doesn't help that statisticians have precise definitions of both [confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/confidence-interval/info) and [prediction intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info) ([there is a big difference!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info)), but not of "uncertainty intervals". In fact, the documentation could be taken to refer to either one, although a "prediction interval interpretation" sounds a little more likely to me.

Can anyone tell us (e.g., by digging through the code) whether these are confidence or prediction intervals?

Comment: +1 I wouldn’t mind hearing why the developers went with their unusual terminology, too.

Comment: @Dave: to be quite honest, I don't think I *really* want to know this...

Comment: (if you haven't already) you can open a github issue and see what the developers say.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From digging through the code as you suggest it seems that they are prediction intervals. Specifically the model is fit by sampling a posterior with Stan (line 1249-1266 in [prophet.R](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/374676500795aec9d5cbc7fe5f7a96bf00489809/R/R/prophet.R#L1249)) and the interval is based on draws from the posterior predictive distribution. See line 1542 of the file [prophet.R](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/main/R/R/prophet.R#L1542-L1542), which I reproduce below.

```r
#' Prophet uncertainty intervals for yhat and trend
#'
#' @param m Prophet object.
#' @param df Prediction dataframe.
#'
#' @return Dataframe with uncertainty intervals.
#'
#' @keywords internal
predict_uncertainty <- function(m, df) {
  sim.values <- sample_posterior_predictive(m, df)
  # Add uncertainty estimates
  lower.p <- (1 - m$interval.width)/2
  upper.p <- (1 + m$interval.width)/2

  intervals <- cbind(
    t(apply(t(sim.values$yhat), 2, stats::quantile, c(lower.p, upper.p),
        na.rm = TRUE)),
t(apply(t(sim.values$trend), 2, stats::quantile, c(lower.p, upper.p),
            na.rm = TRUE))
  )

  colnames(intervals) <- paste(rep(c('yhat', 'trend'), each=2),
                               c('lower', 'upper'), sep = "_")

  return(dplyr::as_tibble(intervals))
}
```

See also the `sample_model` function that is called from `sample_posterior_predictive`, which shows exactly how the `yhat`s are calculated [on line 1573](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/374676500795aec9d5cbc7fe5f7a96bf00489809/R/R/prophet.R#L1573):

```r
sample_model <- function(m, df, seasonal.features, iteration, s_a, s_m) {
  trend <- sample_predictive_trend(m, df, iteration)

  beta <- m$params$beta[iteration,]
  Xb_a = as.matrix(seasonal.features) %*% (beta * s_a) * m$y.scale
  Xb_m = as.matrix(seasonal.features) %*% (beta * s_m)

  sigma <- m$params$sigma_obs[iteration]
  noise <- stats::rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 0, sd = sigma) * m$y.scale

  return(list("yhat" = trend * (1 + Xb_m) + Xb_a + noise,
              "trend" = trend))
}
```

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out that posterior predictive distribution - > prediction intervals relies on the assumption that the model is the true model.   Put differently, if you create a model with Prophet that is missing key elements of the DGP, don't be surprised when the "prediction intervals" are poorly calibrated.

Comment: Yes I agree. Of course something similar will be true for any type of model; no kind of interval will save you from a bad model